# Catch Shape Hyperlink Click on an Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a private subroutine on an Excel sheet that looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Call removeClient(Target.Parent.Row)
End Sub
```

It successfully catches normal hyperlinks. However, shapes with hyperlinks won't trigger this action when called. As these shapes are generated dynamically, I can't use a "Private Sub Shape1_Click" event either.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.onAction` property

like so

```
Sub t()

Dim s As Shape

Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 400, 70, 50, 50)
s.OnAction = "test_macro"

End Sub

Sub test_macro()
    MsgBox "hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: That's really cool! Is there any way I can add arguments send to the subroutine/function? I'd need to send the name of the shape that was clicked.

Comment: Debug.Print Application.Caller in your test_macro